# Concatenate list items if items don't ends with "."

Tags: python

I have a list of strings and I want to concatenate my items if they don't end with a "."

```py
my_list=["This is my first string.","This is my second string, ","this is the middle of my second string","and this is the end of my second string."]
for index in range(len(my_list)):
    text=my_list[index]:
        if not text.endswith("."):
```

Expected 
`["This is my first string.","This is my second string, this is the middle of my second string and this is the end of my second string"]`

Comment: Please post the rest of the code after `if`.

Comment: `"".join(my_list).split(".")` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one approach using `str.join` with `str.split`.

**Ex:**

```
my_list=["This is my first string.","This is my second string, ","this is the middle of my second string","and this is the end of my second string."]
result = [i.strip() + "." for i in " ".join(my_list).strip().split(".") if i]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['This is my first string.',
 'This is my second string,  this is the middle of my second string and this is the end of my second string.']
```

Comment: there's a space missing, maybe `" ".join([s.strip() for s in my_list]).split(".")`?

Comment: hm my suggestion puts a space also in front of 'This...' - not totally correct as well

Comment: `str.strip` should fix that

Comment: that puts two spaces inbetween: `string,  this` - more complicated than I thought...

Comment: really clean: `result = [i.strip() + "." for i in (" ".join([s.strip() for s in my_list])).split(".") if i]`